# Android Notification.MediaStyle not responding to MediaSession updates

Tags: android, android-notifications

As per the `Notification.MediaStyle` doc, attaching a `MediaSession.Token` to the given MediaStyle should hook it to the associated `MediaSession` object.

Quoted Below:

> Finally, if you attach a MediaSession.Token using setMediaSession(MediaSession.Token), the System UI can identify this as a notification representing an active media session and respond accordingly (by showing album artwork in the lockscreen, for example).

The doc then goes to give a code snippet of using MediaStyle in a notification as follows:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
    .setContentTitle("Track title")     // these three lines are optional
    .setContentText("Artist - Album")   // if you use
    .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap))      // setMediaSession(token)
    .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
        .setMediaSession(mySession))
    .build();
```

Clearly stating (from the word **optional**) that the ContentTitle/ContentText parameter are not necessary when used with the token object (likely auto-populated by the MediaStyle instance).

Whilst trying to implement this MediaStyle to a music player I am currently building, I noticed that the notification styled with MediaStyle was not being updated at all despite the music player updating the metadata and playback state repeatedly throughout the process. The only thing present was a blank notification with the notification's "small icon" which gets stretched beyond proportion to a large icon when the view is expanded.

To illustrate this problem, I created a tiny test app below which contains two buttons. One button updates the notification (creates a new one with MediaStyle and sends to to the Notification Manager). The other button generates metadata and a fake playback state to simulate playback. I noticed no matter what combinations of buttons I pressed in whatever order, the notification would not update with the style I wanted it to update with.

The following denotes the activity class that represents my test case. Most is boilerplate Activity code, the last two methods `updateNotification()` and `updateState()` are linked to the two buttons' onClick attribute and facilitate as OnClickListeners.

```
public class MediaStyleTestActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaSession mSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_style_test);

        mSession = new MediaSession(this, "TestSession");
        mSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSession.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_media_style_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void updateState(View v){
        MediaMetadata.Builder mMetaBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

        mMetaBuilder.putText(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "Blue Jeans");
        mMetaBuilder.putText(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, "Born to Die");
        mMetaBuilder.putText(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Lana Del Rey");
        mMetaBuilder.putText(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, "Lana Del Rey");
        mMetaBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, 3);
        mMetaBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS, 15);
        mMetaBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISC_NUMBER, 1);

        Bitmap albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.album_art);

        mMetaBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt);

        PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder();

        stateBuilder.setActiveQueueItemId(MediaSession.QueueItem.UNKNOWN_ID);

        long actions = PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_STOP | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS;

        stateBuilder.setActions(actions);
        stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f);

        mSession.setMetadata(mMetaBuilder.build());
        mSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
    }

    public void updateNotification(View v){
        Notification.Builder nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        nBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        nBuilder.setShowWhen(false);
        nBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        nBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        nBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken()));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(100, nBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Please ignore the improper use of MediaSession here, this is only for demonstration purposes.

The app as present on my device:

[image: Screenshot of demonstration app]

I did notice that the lockscreen was being updated with the album art, but no more:

[image: Lockscreen containing album art as background]

As mentioned, no matter what combination of MediaSession/MediaStyle/Notification updates I try, none seem to result in the content view of the notification to populate with the metadata provided (including setting a valid `MediaSession.QueueItem` not shown in the example). Logcat doesn't show anything at all even under verbose for the notification not going well or failing.

Unless I'm missing something really obvious here, what am I doing wrong?

---

Just as additional information, I am **not** using any of the compatibility libraries for notifications and MediaSession. This component of my app is for API 21+ only so there is no need for backward compatibility support.

In my production code, the actual MediaSession is held in a foreground service and I've tried updating from various threads (UI/whatever media thread android uses/my own custom thread) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. `setContentTitle`, `setContextText` as well as `setLargeIcon` are required as of today to show notification title, text and image. (doc issue which is being addressed)

Aside: Also note that you should call `mediaSession.setActive(true)`

Comment: So are you suggesting the official documentation is incorrect? And I forgot to call setActive() to true within the example but I did in my production code to no avail.

Comment: Yes the documentation is being fixed. (setActive does not change this behavior but is need to make the session discoverable hence mentioned as an aside)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. But then what is the use of passing the MediaSession token to the MediaStyle if the notification has to be manually updated on every playback state/metadata change? Seems like each new track played would yield a new MediaStyle being created (as part of the notification building process) make the whole session token being passed to MediaStyle rather redundant.

Comment: Different media apps may want to map metadata fields to notification title/text differently, and most apps need to update the notification actions based on the playback state, so they need a MediaController.Callback anyway. The session token is important for the system UI to get extra information not available on the notification object, such as a high res album art for the lock screen.